# Homotopy fixed point spectral sequence for cooperation algebra

Tags: homotopy-theory

For a finite group $G$ acting on a spectrum $X$, there is a homotopy fixed point spectral sequence calculating $X^{hG}$ with signature
$$E_2^{p, q} = H^p(G, \pi_q X) \implies \pi_{q-p}(X^{hG}).$$
Consider the big Morava stabilizer subgroup $\mathbb{G}_n$ and finite subgroup $G$. I am interested in computing the cooperation algebra $\pi_*((E_n \wedge E_n)^{h(G \times G)})$. There are many methods to doing this, but I am curious: are there any attempts at computing this via a HFPSS of the form
$$E_2^{p, q} = H^p(G, \pi_q(E_n^{hG} \wedge E_n)) \implies \pi_{q-p}((E_n \wedge E_n)^{h(G \times G)})?$$